# Sending music directly from MIC to LS

Tags: linux, audio

How can I tell linux to send directly from my microphone to my loudspeaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your audio system.

By default, your mic input should be already send to your speaker.

Please specify your problem a little bit more in detail.

A common problem is, that you will have to unmute your mic channel.

The major audio systems for linux since 2.6 is [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/).
The default mixer application is curses based and can be opened on the terminal with `alsamixer`. Try this, select your channels with the arrow keys and press <kbd>m</kbd> to unmute them.

If you are using an older installation, maybe your audio system is [OSS](http://www.opensound.com/linux.html). The default mixing application for this one is `vmix`.

If you are using some other setup which could include [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) or [PulseAudio](http://www.pulseaudio.org/), provide us with more details.